# C++ char[] memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm new to C++ (porting from Java), and I cannot understand whether or not I have a memory leak in my code.

this is the basis of my code (it's far more complicated, I bring the important places where memory can leak)

```
char message[15000];
char allMessages[102400];
int allMessagesCounter;

int main() {
    connect() \\this works just fine
    openThreadAndGetAllMessages() \\ here I get each time a message to my message char array and concatenate it into allMessages array using allMessagesCounter
    cout << allMessages;
    disconnect() \\works just fine as well
}
```

My question is, do I need to free the message[] and allMessages[]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. In general, in C++, if you use the keyword `new` then you should also `delete` later. Your variables are allocated statically, and do not need to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

No you do not because they are not dynamically allocated. You only need to call `delete` if memory is allocated with `new`:

```
 int *a = new int [5]; //must call delete [] or memory leak
 int b [5]; //no need
```

Comment: This is incorrect. As `message` and `allMessages` are *not* declared in the body of a function, they are *not* allocated on the stack. They are statically allocated, meaning they are probably in the `.bss` section of the program, and that they are "allocated" when the program is loaded by the OS.

Comment: Your last sentence is true, but the rest is not.